# Java socket read blocked/failed no exceptions thrown , setsotimer was set (TCP/IP)

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

We recently saw this error. Server sent a response message (MSG1) to one of its clients (size of msg > 64KB). Something happened at the client's read, this message was not received at all. Neither the SocketTimeOutException nor the IOException were thrown. Server tried to send another message (MSG2) but was blocked in its write (the buffers at the TCP/IP level could have been full with MSG1). 2 hours elapsed before we realised this and had to restart everything. We managed to simulate the same thing by making client read slower (by pausing for 2s) and making the server send similar messages (size >64KB) as usual.

In the first place, we could see no reason why the client would read slowly, for months it has been able to cope with such messages without the problem. I would like to know (a) what causes this kind of deadlock say if the client's read

`getInputStream().read(byBuf)`
 is slower than the server's write 
`getOutputStream().write(MSG1)`
(`byBuf` is a Byte buffer of size 512Bytes)
(b) Could a socket error or n/w error cause such blockage otherwise?

We are using jdk 1.6.0.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you can reproduce this with your test, you should fire up Wireshark and look at the network trace for what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The write blocks if the socket send buffer is full, which implies that the receiver's socket receive buffer is full, which implies that the reader is slower than the writer. As your reader was blocked in a read this suggests a network or kernel problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would blocking write stall indefinitely when the buffers get full and it fails to obtain an immediate response?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a network problem - perhaps a congested link or broken firewall between the two hosts. "Reproducing" the problem by adding delays to the client won't tell you anything interesting, merely that the OS-level buffering works as designed :)

You need to find out why the packets are being delayed, which generally means tcpdump/wireshark at both ends. If the issue only occurs every few months though then this is probably overkill - focus on improving how the app handles this scenario and/or how you detect if it reoccurs.

As an aside, Java doesn't allow a write timeout to be set, so to recover from this scenario the *reader* should call `setSoTimeout` before reading, then close the socket if a read throws `SocketTimeoutException`. The write should then fail with `SocketException` ("connection reset by peer"), although this may take a while if the link is slow/intermittent.

Comment: We are working on handling such situation (if it ever occurs again) more gracefully than before. We were quite certain that the buffers were full, but failed to understand why read() stalled without throwing any exceptions. We assumed that whatever we saw in the first place was due to a n/w problem. Thanks a lot for the reply1